# How to exclude an entire directory from Android 6 Auto Backup?

Tags: android, backup, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'd like to configure the Android 6 Auto Backup feature to exclude all files in entire directories (both in "files" and "external"), also some specific extensions should be excluded. Will wildcards like *.* and *.tn-png work for the path value?
I cannot explicitly define all files since these are created at run-time.

```
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/mybackupscheme"
```

where mybackupscheme would for example be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <exclude domain="file" path="device-links.xml"/>
    <exclude domain="file" path="*.tn-png"/>
    <exclude domain="file" path="links/*.*"/>
    <exclude domain="external" path="external-links/*.*" />
</full-backup-content>
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html) says:

> path: Specifies a file or folder to include in or exclude from backup.
>   Note that: **This attribute does not support wildcard or regex syntax.**

So you can't use wildcards.

But you can use `exclude` to exclude entire directories

> `<exclude>` - Specifies a file or folder to exclude during backup.

If you have really complex file structure, you can implement own `BackupAgent` and overide [`onFullBackup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupAgent.html#onFullBackup(android.app.backup.FullBackupDataOutput)) method.

> You can't easily express the set of files you want to backup with
>   XML rules. In these rare cases, you can implement a BackupAgent that
>   overrides onFullBackup(FullBackupDataOutput) to store what you want.
>   To retain the system's default implementation, call the corresponding
>   method on the superclass with super.onFullBackup().

Comment: is the correct usage   <exclude domain="file" path="."/> ? . indicates entire directory?

Comment: I mean entore directory, which you want to exclude, like `<exclude domain="file" path="myfiles/mydir"/>`. `<exclude domain="file" path="."/>` should exclude all files within your app's files folder.